# Should a class be thread-safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Should a thread-safe mechanism be added when a class is developed and it is known that this class will be used in multi-threaded environment (not always however) or leave it to the user?

Comment: We don't build bullet proof tanks for no reason.  Time is money.

Comment: What do you mean "multi-threaded environment"? In the same Program?

Comment: Well, do you mean 'thread-safe' in that one instance is safe to use from multiple threads because of internal locking, or 'thread-safe' in that no statics are used so each thread can safely create and use their own object instance/s, or what?

Comment: @PeterRader yes. to use object from multiple threads

Comment: Without knowing more about the actual application nor the type of class nor its usage pattern we'd be very lucky to guess even a remotely objective correct answer.

Comment: @KillianDS that's exactly what i would like to hear)

Comment: @Ivars ok, yes the class should be thread-save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, it's more flexible to leave it to the user. For example, consider a map-type container. Suppose the application needs to atomically move something from one map to another map. In this case, the user needs to lock both maps before the insert-erase sequence.

Having such a scenario be automatically taken care of somehow by your class would probably be inelegant, because it's naturally something that happens across objects, and because there may be many such scenarios, each slightly different.